# Thread creation by extending Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a simple example about creating a thread by extending the `Thread` class.

```
class Count extends Thread {

    Count() {
        super("my extending thread");
        System.out.println("my new thread is started " + this);
        start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("count " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("my thread run is over");
        }
    }

}

public class Multi2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Count c = new Count();
        try {
            while (c.isAlive()) {
                System.out.println("main thread is alive untill child thread is alive");
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("main thread is over");
        }
    }
}
```

And my output was this.

```
my new thread is started Thread[my extending thread,5,main]
main thread is alive untill child thread is alive
count 0
count 1
main thread is alive untill child thread is alive
count 2
main thread is alive untill child thread is alive
count 3
count 4
main thread is alive untill child thread is alive
count 5
main thread is alive untill child thread is alive
count 6
count 7
main thread is alive untill child thread is alive
count 8
main thread is alive untill child thread is alive
count 9
my thread run is over
main thread is over
```

My questions are,

01. How come `main thread is alive untill child thread is alive`output printed before 
`count 0
count 1`

02.How come `main thread is alive untill child thread is alive`output keep printing withing the output of `run()` method?

Please help me to figure this out.

Thank you.

Comment: More importantly, why do you think that the "main thread is alive..." *shouldn't* keep printing out?  Note that your code structure is not good. For one, you should be implementing Runnable and not extending Thread, and you almost never want a Thread to start itself in its constructor.

Comment: Because that's how threads work

Comment: 01. what else did you expect? 02. what else did you expect? How do you expect multiple running Threads to behave in a multithread environment?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thank you for your input. First of all I'm new to multi-threading concept. I'm trying to get a grip of this. So please bear this with me and explain.

Comment: I wouldn't dare try to explain so complex a topic when I already know that many decent tutorials are in existence, are easy to find, and would explain all of this **far** better than I could hope to do. Please consider availing yourself of these resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count has this line:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Your main program has this line:

```
Thread.sleep(1500);
```

Clearly, you're going to get 2 main prints for every 3 count prints. That's why 0 and 1 are next to each other.

As for why you see the main print before the count prints, you can see this:

```
Count c = new Count();
try {
while (c.isAlive()) {
    System.out.println("main thread is alive untill child thread is alive");
    Thread.sleep(1500);
```

You've fired off your `c` but until your JVM performs a context switch to actually run that thread, you might not see results. The truth is you may, on some systems, see your counter before that. Often, because it's so close to when it kicks off and hasn't yielded yet, you'll see the main print before the counter.

For your second part, your `main thread is...` keeps printing because it has a loop that tells it to print until your counter thread is no longer alive. They both use `System.out` so when you look at your console you see them both there.

Comment: although the original plan to get  2 main prints for every 3 count prints why it doesn't print that way in that order? I mean some times it prints 1 main points - 2 count points or 1 main point - 1 count point.  why is that?

Comment: well the 1500, 4500, 7500 etc are easily going to fall between the 1000 and 2000, 4000 and 5000, and 7000 and 8000 respectively. The 3000, 6000 and 9000 statements, however, will be racing with the 3000, 6000, and 9000 print statements. You won't have a high likelihood of predicting which of those is going to be printed first - they're both supposed to print at essentially the same time. The best you can say is whichever wins the first race is LIKELY to win future races, but it may indeed be different just by "up-arrow, enter" to run it again.