# JPanel implementation repaint not firing PaintComponent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a java swing application that creates a JFrame with my own implemented JPanel. This JPanel is supposed to hold a matrix that should be repainted after every change.
This matrix contain elements (in my application these are "robots") represented with circles in their fitting matrix cell.

Inside my panel I'm trying to move one of those robots (meaning - move of the circles to a neighbor cell in the matrix) 30 times, and redraw this matrix after every movement. However, when I call repaint after moving the robot, the `paintComponent()` is not fired. I don't know what should be changed in order for this to work as expected.

Heres the part in my code that relates to the problem:

**RobotsWorldSimulator**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class RobotsWorldSimulator {

    public static int robotsWorldSize;
    public static int CELL_HEIGHT = 20;
    public static int CELL_WIDTH = 20;
    private static RobotsWorld robotsWorld;
    private static JFrame mainFrame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        inputWorldSize();

        robotsWorld = new RobotsWorld(robotsWorldSize);

        mainFrame = new JFrame("Robots world!");

        JPanel robotsWorldPanel = new RobotsWorldPanel(robotsWorld);

        mainFrame.setSize(robotsWorldPanel.getWidth() + CELL_WIDTH * 1, robotsWorldPanel.getHeight() + CELL_HEIGHT * 2);
        mainFrame.add(robotsWorldPanel);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private static void inputWorldSize() {
        boolean validWorldSize = false;

        while (!validWorldSize){
            // prompt the user to enter their wanted size
            String worldSizeString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(mainFrame, "Enter the robot's world size (Between 1 to 99)");

            if (worldSizeString == null)
                break;
            try{
                robotsWorldSize = Integer.parseInt(worldSizeString);
            } catch (Exception ex){
                continue;
            }

            validWorldSize = robotsWorldSize > 0 && robotsWorldSize < 100;
        }

        robotsWorld = new RobotsWorld(robotsWorldSize);
    }
}
```

**RobotsWorldPanel**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RobotsWorldPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int ROBOTS_NUMBER = 5;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_MOVES_TO_MOVE = 30;

    private RobotsWorld robotsWorld;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private static Position[] robotsPositions = new Position[ROBOTS_NUMBER];
    private static Map<Integer, Color> robotsColors = new HashMap<>();

    public RobotsWorldPanel(RobotsWorld robotsWorld) {
        setSize(RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH * RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize,
                RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT * RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize );
        this.robotsWorld = robotsWorld;
        initializeRobots();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize, RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize ));

        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        drawGameBoard(g);
        drawRobots(g);
        moveRandomRobot();
    }

    private void drawGameBoard(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, i * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT,
                    RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH * RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize,
                    i * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH, 0,
                    i * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH,
                    RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT * RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize);
        }
    }

    private void drawRobots(Graphics g) {
        for (int robotIndex = 0; robotIndex < ROBOTS_NUMBER; robotIndex++){
            Position robotPosition = robotsPositions[robotIndex];
            Robot targetRobot = robotsWorld.getRobot(robotPosition);
            Color robotColor = robotsColors.get(targetRobot.getRobotId());
            drawRobot(g, robotPosition.getX(), robotPosition.getY(), robotColor, targetRobot.getRobotDirection());
        }
    }

    private void drawRobot(Graphics g, int row, int col, Color robotColor, int robotDirection) {
        g.setColor(robotColor);
        g.fillOval(row * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH, col * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT,
                RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH, RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT);

        String robotDirectionSign = "";
        if (robotDirection == Robot.DIRECTION_DOWN){
            robotDirectionSign = "v";
        } else if (robotDirection == Robot.DIRECTION_RIGHT){
            robotDirectionSign = ">";
        } else if (robotDirection == Robot.DIRECTION_UP){
            robotDirectionSign = "^";
        } else if (robotDirection == Robot.DIRECTION_LEFT){
            robotDirectionSign = "<";
        }

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString(robotDirectionSign,  (row * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH) + RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_WIDTH / 2,
                (col * RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT) + RobotsWorldSimulator.CELL_HEIGHT / 2);
    }

    // Generating random color for each robot
    private void initializeRobots() {

        // Inserting new robots to the world
        for (int robotIndex = 0; robotIndex < ROBOTS_NUMBER; robotIndex++) {
            // Set random position
            int x = random.nextInt(RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize);
            int y = random.nextInt(RobotsWorldSimulator.robotsWorldSize);
            Position robotPosition = new Position(x,y);
            robotsPositions[robotIndex] = robotPosition;

            try {
                robotsWorld.addRobot(robotPosition);
            } catch (IllegalPositionException ex){
                return;
            }

            Robot addedRobot = robotsWorld.getRobot(robotPosition);

            // Adding the robot to the colors map
            robotsColors.put(addedRobot.getRobotId(), new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat()));
        }
    }

    // Moves a random robot a specified number of moves
    private void moveRandomRobot() {
        int randomRobot = random.nextInt(ROBOTS_NUMBER);
        Position robotPosition = robotsPositions[randomRobot];

        int possibleWaysToMove = Robot.NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS;

        for (int moveNumber = 0; moveNumber < NUMBER_OF_MOVES_TO_MOVE && possibleWaysToMove > 0; moveNumber++){
            try{
                robotsWorld.moveRobot(robotPosition);

                // THE PROBLEM IS HERE - WHY ISN'T paintComponent fired??
                repaint();

                // 1 second sleep for graphics purposes.
//                try {
//                    Thread.sleep(10000);
//                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }

                possibleWaysToMove = Robot.NUMBER_OF_DIRECTIONS;

            } catch (IllegalPositionException ex) {
                // Turns the robot right in case of failure.
                Robot targetRobot = robotsWorld.getRobot(robotPosition);
                targetRobot.turnRight();
                possibleWaysToMove--;
            }
        }

        if (possibleWaysToMove == 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "The robot in position" + robotPosition + "has no where left to move!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move repaint call at the end of `paintComponent()` and see if it works. Most likely for loop's condition in `moveRandomRobot()` is always false.

Comment: The loop in moveRandomRobot() is blocking the event thread. The call to repaint()merely tells the event loop to repaint the component as soon as it gets the chance, but that cannot happen until moveRandomRobo() returns and the event thread can continue. You need to put that in a separate thread.

Comment: Use [Swing Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53701618/3992939) to repeatedly move robots without blocking / flooding EDT.  For more help post [mcve]